# how to ensure yum install was successful in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, yum

I have a shell script which checks if there is an internet connection (by pinging google), and then calls

```
yum install packageA packageB --assumeyes
```

How would I confirm that the packages were installed (or were already installed)?  Do I make another yum call and parse the output (I presume this gets very complicated if the system is in another language)?

Comment: You could grep or parse /var/log/yum.log

Comment: Setting `LC_ALL=C` should switch to English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [this random post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/yum-update-script-with-return-value-822471/), it looks like yum returns an error code to the shell. You can test this out by running a command and then immediately (as the next command) doing:

```
echo $?
```

That will print the previous command's return code. Success should be 0, failure of some kind nonzero. But that's just a guess since I don't have a box accessible to me at the moment. :)

Comment: That should be how it works. My version of yum exits with success even on certain failures; `yum install non-existant-package && echo "I think that went well"`

Comment: As noted above, there are a number of cases where `yum` returns 0 even though I would consider it to have failed, e.g. you specified a package name but that package could not be found in any configured repository or you specified a file name but the file was not found.  `yum`'s exit status is just not that useful.

Answer (score 13):

I've used the following method, which might not be foolproof, but seems to work:

Assuming the variable `PACKAGES` contains the list of packages you want to install, then:

1. Run `yum -y install $PACKAGES` (I assume if this is a script, you really want to pass `-y` to avoid prompting).
2. Check its exit status in order to detect *some* failure conditions.
3. Run `rpm --query --queryformat "" $PACKAGES`, which will output nothing for each package that was installed successfully, and will output `package <name> is not installed` for each failure.
4. Check its exit status, which appears to be the number of packages that were not successfully installed, i.e. will be 0 on success as usual.

This will only work if `PACKAGES` contains plain package names that `yum` is expected to find in a repository, not if it contains other things that `yum` accepts like URLs, file names or `Provides:` names.

Answer (score 6):

By ping google.com does not ensure the yum repo you trying to connect is available

The command to check whether a package is already installed :-

```
yum list installed PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: thanks ajreal -- I was just pinging google to see if dns was working and if there was connectivity.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer the question, it answers my question! +1 for you