# how can i use grep result from a variable in if/else statment

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, variables, grep

i am trying to create a condition statement that checks if the grep found if a package is installed.
if it is true , then the package should not be installed , and if it is false , then the package should be installed.
i am always getting the same result package is not installed no matter which value i put
please help  (in my case the all packages are installed and grep finds a match.
here is code:

```
chk1=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdevtools) 
chk2=$(yum list installed | grep rpmbuild)
chk3=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdev)
if [[ $chk1 -ne 0 && "$chk2" -ne 0 && "$chk3" -ne 0 ]];then
   echo "package exists"
   sleep 5
else
   echo "package doesn't exists installing .."
   sleep 5
   sudo yum install wget -y
   wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
   sudo yum install rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm -y
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447011/how-to-ensure-yum-install-was-successful-in-a-shell-script

Comment: You probably want to add the `-w` flag (whole-word match) to `grep` -- without it, `grep rpmdev` will match "rpmdevtools" (and probably other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing 2 types of results here : result (i.e. displayed text) and return value.

## TL;DR

You can verify if the variable `$chkX` is not empty with `[[ ! -z ${chkX} ]]`, such as :

```sh
if [[ ! -z ${chk1} ]] && [[ ! -z ${chk2} ]] && [[ ! -z ${chk3} ]]; then
[...]
```

Or you can do something like this, based on exit codes.

```sh
yum list installed | grep -q vim
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  # do your stuff here when package is installed
else
  #.. do your stuff here when package isn't installed ..
fi
```

or

```sh
if yum list installed | grep -q 'vim' ;then
  # do your stuff here when package is installed
else
  # .. do your stuff here when package isn't installed ..
fi
```

---

When executing in a subshell through $(yum ...) you are storing the result (i.e. displayed text) that's echoed by the command.
For instance:

```
$> yum list installed | grep vim
vim-common.x86_64                                 2:8.2.3755-1.fc35                    @updates
```

If you want the return code or exit code, it's accessible through `$?`.
For example:

```sh
$> ls
[...]
$> echo $?
0
$> ls toto
ls: cannot access 'toto': No such file or directory
$> echo $?
2
```

Note every command changes the exit code.
So accessing twice `$?` will change its value.

```sh
$> ls toto
ls: cannot access 'toto': No such file or directory
$> echo $?
2
$> echo $?
0
```

In your case, you're testing if the text given by `yum` is mathematically equal to 0:

```sh
chk3=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdev)
if [[ $chk1 -ne 0 && "$chk2" -ne 0 && "$chk3" -ne 0 ]];then
                                             ^^^^^^
```

It's not possible because :

- no package found -> empty variable
- one or many package found -> single or multiline text with package information.
- and you'll never get `0`.

If you run it with test you have various cases of failure:

```sh
# note: rpmdevtools is not installed on by computer
$> chk1=$(yum list installed | grep rpmdevtools) 
$> test $chk1 -ne 0
bash: test: -ne: unary operator expected

# multiple vim-* packages are installed
$> chk1=$(yum list installed | grep vim) 
$> test $chk1 -ne 0
bash: test: too many arguments
```

Comment: truly thank mate!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with yum, there may be a better way to check, but this will make your if statement work:

```
if
    yum list installed | grep -q rpmdevtools &&
    yum list installed | grep -q rpmbuild &&
    yum list installed | grep -q rpmdev
then
```

I also recommend adding `-w` to grep, to match a whole word.

If `yum list installed` is a slow command, consider saving the output in a variable, and grepping that (instead of running it three times):

```
list=$(yum list installed)

if
    echo "$list" | grep -q rpmdevtools &&
    echo "$list" | grep -q rpmbuild &&
    echo "$list" | grep -q rpmdev
then
```

Comment: You can add a `-q` to the grep commands to suppress output.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `-ne` checks for numeric equality; of course the output from `grep` is not going to be the number 0, so all of your checks fail.

You seem to be overcomplicating things significantly anyway. `yum list installed` optionally accepts a list of packages to check.

```
if yum list installed rpmdevtools rpmbuild rpmdev >/dev/null 2>&1
then
   echo "$0: package exists" >&1
else
   echo "$0: package doesn't exist; installing ..." >&2
   sudo yum install -y wget
   wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
   sudo yum install -y rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
fi
```

Notice the convention for diagnostic messages to include the script name `$0` and print to standard error `>&2`, and how we avoid the absolutely user-hostile abomination of `sleep`ing in the middle.  If you want to give users a chance to decide whether they really want to proceed with the planned action, display a separate prompt (and ideally make it possible to override from the command line, just like `yum install -y` lets you say you don't want a prompt).